# Workflow progression in Argo Workflows

Tags: argo-workflows

I will be executing over 10k DAG tasks in an Argo Workflow. I need to send the current state of these tasks: When they start (i.e. running) and finish (i.e. failed, successful) to an external system. How can I accomplish this using Argo Workflows?

I want to avoid the need for a sidecar container to run alongside each task solely for the purpose of retrieving and transmitting the task status.

I thought of adding a custom metric to every template that will inform the state of the task but not sure if it could be a good solution. Even if it works, I am worried about the high cardinality that it could create.

Thanks!